# Footer moving and sticking on lower resolutions

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to build a page with a footer. It looks fine in 1600x900, but as soon as I scale down the footer moves to dead center and won't budge. Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
#Container{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}

#Banner_Container {
 position:relative; 
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 0.2%;


}

#Banner { 
 color: #FF7538;
 font-style: oblique;
 font-family: Courier New;
 line-height: 1;
 float: left;
}

#Index {
 width: 80%;
 background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.9);
 border: 10px solid #ED9121;
 border-style: outset;
 padding-top: 2%;
 float:left;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 30%;
 min-width: 10%;
 max-width: 80%;
}

#nav {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  width: 15%;
  float: right;
  border: 5px solid #ED9121;
  border-style: inset;
  margin-top: 35%;
  margin-left: 82%;
  min-width: 5%;
  max-width: 20%;

}

#footer{
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 110%;
}
```

I was requested to do this in PHP

**index.php**

```
<?php
  echo "<div id='Container'>";
     include("banner.php");
     include("navbar.php");
     include("intro.php");
     include("footer.php");
  echo"</div>";
?>
```

So I have it separated like this

**intro.php**

```
<?php
    echo "<div  id='Index'>
            <div  id='Info'>
               <img align='left' src='images/stock1.jpg'/>
               <h2 align='left'>Welcome to East End Dental</h2>
               <p>Ipsum</p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
               <img align='right' src='images/stock2.jpg'/><br>
               <h2 align='left'>Quality Guarantee</h2>
               <p>Ipsum</p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

               <div id='summary1'>
                  <center><h2>Our Dental Services</h2>
                  <img src='images/stock3.jpg'/></center>
                  <p>Ipsum<br><br></p>
               </div>
               <div id='summary2'>
                  <center><h2>Meet the Staff</h2>
                  <a href='staff.php'><img src='images/stock4.jpg'/></a    </center>
                  <p>Ipsum.</p>
              </div>
              <div id='summary1'>
                  <center><h2>Contact Us Today</h2>
                  <img src='images/stock5.jpg'/></center>
                  <p>Ipsum</p><br><br>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>";
?>
```

**footer.php**

```
<?php
  echo" <div  id='footer'>
      <center>
         <p>Company Name 2016<br/>
        Designed by <a href='mailto:email@gmail.com'>Name</a></p>
                     <a href='index.php'>Home</a> | <a href='services.php'>Services</a>  | <a href='cerec.php'>CEREC®</a> | <a href='staff.php'>Staff</a> | <a href='contact.php'>Contact</a>
                    </center>
                </div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the footer's `margin-top` set to 110% which will cause the footer to move around at different screen sizes. Percentage-based values are relative and change depending upon the parent container. I made a [JSFiddle to show what this looks like with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/jwzk7q2s/). The problem is faithfully reproducible by resizing the web browser.

To begin to fix this change your footer CSS. If you wanted a sticky/persistent footer that should would look something like this:

```
#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
}
```

I made a [JSFiddle showing the solution so you can see this in action](https://jsfiddle.net/htbsqfgj/1/). This should address the footer floating to another location when the browser window resizes or is shown on a different device.

If you want the footer to just be at the bottom of the page and not stick there you would make this modification to the CSS:

```
#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

This will just make sure the footer stays at the bottom of the content within the page and doesn't appear on the side of the previous element. Since you didn't specify if you were going for a stick footer I'm putting this in just to cover this other scenario.

In any case, hopefully this is the info you need to move forward on your website.

Comment: I tried both. The first one just moved the footer to the middle of the page, and the second one didn't change anything. Thanks all the same. If you have any other suggestions, I'm all ears!

Comment: The first link looks like this in my test (http://grab.by/MNJY) and the second link looks like this (http://grab.by/MNKe) in JSFiddle. So making the change does cause a change in the footer. If you have a link that I can see to take a look that may be better to help diagnose your problem.

Comment: Tried on Jfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/c002ycm8/) and (https://jsfiddle.net/etzgd6gx/) until I can get it live

Comment: Thanks, the JSFiddle helped a lot. You'll see in this JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/7w6ef3p1/9/) that I made a change to the HTML and that gets the footer to appear beneath the rest of the layout. Seeing this I get why you weren't seeing the solution as there was another edit that has to be made in HTML to get this to render properly. So, to recap, move the `footer` div up into the previous container and make the CSS change I had in my second scenario to get a footer that appears centered and beneath the rest of the content.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. So I shouldn't bother with the `include` function for the footer, just put it directly on the page instead. Thanks!